# BMW E90 N52 catalytic code removal

Tags: bmw, catalytic-converter

I want to learn how I can clear catalytic code removal forever.
What software I can use and what tools ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I live in Georgia (country)

Comment: I understand that you are interested in clearing the catalytic code in a BMW E90 N52 engine permanently. However, I must emphasize that tampering with emissions control systems, including removing or bypassing the catalytic converter, is illegal in many countries and regions. It can lead to significant fines and penalties, as well as environmental damage. Moreover, it can void your vehicle's warranty and affect its performance and fuel efficiency. If your vehicle is experiencing issues with the catalytic converter, it's crucial to address the root cause of the problem rather than attempting to